# Don't give me that line

Tags: lateral-thinking, no-computers

Note: This puzzle cannot be solved on the computer. Draw it out on paper and then solve...

```
--------X---------------x-------
|               |              |
X               X              X
|               |              |
-----X------X------X------X-----
|        |             |       |
X        X             X       X
|        |             |       |
----X-----------X----------X----
```

Rules: With a single "line" starting anywhere, pass through each X only once.

Answers can be described (as there is more than one way to do it) or scanned and posted.

Comment: Agreed - this is a duplicate of that question.

Comment: Yes, I guess it is. Sorry about that. I thought I had looked, but not hard enough. Although, I will have to add my own answer to the other question.

Comment: Have you tried folding the paper in half to continue your line after a portal jump?

Comment: I added the answers I remembered to the original post (as mine truly is a duplicate, although slightly different in wording)

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a duplicate. You said (rot13)(gung V arrq gb cnff guebhtu rnpu pncvgny K bayl bapr, ohg V frr n fznyy k.).

Answer (score 1):

> This puzzle cannot be solved. Since you can only pass through an X once, one end of the path must be in each of the three large rectangles, *and* one end must be outside the overall diagram. Since that's four ends, and a line has only two ends, the puzzle cannot be solved as presented. The [referenced duplicate question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1856/draw-a-line-through-all-doors) has as one of its answers a detailed explanation of why it's impossible; a simplified explanation (and the one that I immediately thought of) was included, without diagram, in the story "The Sixteen Keys" in [*Lord Darcy*](http://www.baen.com/lord-darcy.html), a collection of Randall Garret's stories about the eponymous detective.

Comment: Actually it can be solved, but it takes thinking outside the box. I missed that someone else posted the question, but it is doable.

Comment: @ben-NabiyDerush If you have a solution that hasn't already been posted on the linked duplicate question, feel free to post another solution there.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain - Done.

Comment: @ben-NabiyDerush See my comment on your question. (Cryptography involved)